# Two sorting parameters in the same query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a query that orders for two specific fields. That the word of a certain field appears first and when it returns this ordering also bring me with the highest prices.
I managed to do the first condition but I am not able to apply the second one which should show me the highest prices too

```
[{$addFields: {
 sortNum: {
  $cond: [
   {
    $eq: [
     '$contato',
     'WHATSAPP'
    ]
   },
   0,
   {
    $cond: [
     {
      $eq: [
       '$contato',
       'LANDLINE'
      ]
     },
     1,
     2
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}}, {$sort: {
 sortNum: 1
}}]
```

[result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHDu9.png)

But I still can't get back with the higher prices too.

Comment: You can use both fields in sort stage, `{ $sort: { sortNum: 1, preco: -1 } }`

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly that detail that was missing.